# Add a parent route in ember for existing routes

Tags: ember.js

Here is my problem, 
assume I am having an ember app with following ember route configuration:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('todos', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('view', {
      path: "/:id"
    });
  });
  this.route('articles', function() {
    this.route('view', {
      path: "/:id"
    });
    this.route('new');
  });
});
```

Now i want to add the add the prefix for each route based on some user information i would be fetching.
For eg:
Below are the two user information

```
dev = {
 id: 1, 
 workspace: 'DEV'
}
qa = {
 id: 2,
 workspace:'TEST'
}
```

once the `dev` is landing in the app, route must be like:
todos:

```
/DEV/todos/new
```

and same for the other users.
once the `qa` is landing in the page, route must be like:

```
/TEST/todos/new
```

to solve this i know we generate the parent route and add all the other route as child, need to change the file structure for this case.

Here is Ember :

```
ember-cli: 2.13.3,
ember-data: 2.18.5
```

Comment: Serving two separate application using subdirectories `/DEV` and `/TEST` is not an option? Do you have the requirement to switch between the `workspace` without a full page refresh? Just asking cause your example sounds like development and staging environments. In most cases you won't use the same app instance for both but different deployments (with maybe different build- or run-time configuration).

Answer (score 2):

This is straight forward in Ember.js using the router's path as URL paths can be customized easily.

For your case, the `todos` route should have a dynamic segment (say, `workplace`) and hence, the router entry will be like:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('todos', { path: '/:workplace/todos' }, function() {
    this.route('new');
    ...
  });
});
```

And if you are transitioning to new todo page using `this.transitionTo('todos.new', 'TEST')`, then URL will be updated as `TEST/todos/new`.

[This twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/bc0016536f92c45e9e1a86af0add613c?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) has a tiny demo. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Yes, Got your point, but now think like, all the route mapping should have the `/:workplace` prefix to it, and i have the huge structure of this router mapping, contains a lots of nested route as well,  and this for the existing app, where some place `link-to` component has been used.

Comment: I guess, for your structure, the `/:workplace` segment should be added only for the parent/root route entry and all child will inherit them. If that's not true in your case, a problem reproduction in a twiddle would really help.

Comment: that's exactly the situation is, i have to inherit all the routes form '/:workplace'